# cannot inherit from final FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

i'm trying to create a simple Android with Firebase notification push and when i'm going to generate the apk, i get this error: error: cannot inherit from `final FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver`
This is my `FirebaseMessagingService class`, which is marked as red.

```
package com.provedor.cn.pushnot2;

import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;

public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver {
}
```

**in manifest:**

```
    <service
        android:name=".MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: full image of my manifest: https://i.imgur.com/l8qomkz.png / gradle module app https://i.imgur.com/qvNqPPe.png / and gradle project https://i.imgur.com/UUYTAIG.png

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the import from:

```
import com.google.firebase.iid.FirebaseInstanceIdReceiver;
```

to

```
import com.google.firebase.messaging.FirebaseMessagingService;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your class should extend

```
FirebaseMessagingService
```

and then you can override method `onNewToken(String token);` and `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message);`